# Ideal way of triggering an Airflow DAG with config

Tags: config, airflow

Current Structure:
I am currently deploying airflow on the servers. I am having a server dedicated for airflow. There are also few other servers as worker servers, where each server has applications to perform the airflow task.

Usage:
For each DAG, I am using SSHOperators to do SSH commands on the worker servers, to complete the tasks.

Config:
For each task, it will need to access a config file that contains the file paths and keyed values for the operation. The config file is likely to be slightly different for every DAG run.
I do understand that there are many ways to trigger a DAG, including

- passing a config object at run time, either via CLI or REST API
- having a config.json stored on the worker servers, and having each
  task to load it when the task starts
- saving the config information in the airflow admin page, and access the config element using xcom

Concerns:
I am currently passing the config as a JSON string (2-3KB) via REST API, and embed the config in the SSH bash commands
`/task/foo --do-something --config "{{ dag_run.conf["foo"] }}"`.
I am worry if that will one day overload the Airflow database, or someone who mistakenly send a huge config (>10MB).

Questions:
I am wondering what will be the ideal way for triggering an Airflow DAG with config? How is the run_dag config being stored? Is there any garbage collection feature that will clean out the cached config periodically?